# Bat file - Net use from remote desktop not work well in some cases

Tags: windows, batch-file, remote-desktop, net-use

I try to run `.bat` file from remote desktop.

I do it by run the next command:

```
net use m: \\the-ip-of-the-remote-computer mypassword /myuser
// Execution works well
```

then, I try to xcopy from the remote desktop to my computer. So I write this:

```
net use t: \\the-ip-of-the-remote-desktop mypassword /myuser
xcopy \\the-ip-of-the-remote-computer my-libary
```

But in some cases, this command is not execute well.

I also try this, and it doesn't work:

```
net use m: \\the-ip-of-the-remote-desktop mypassword /myuser
xcopy net use t: \\the-ip-of-the-remote-computer mypassword /myuser my-libary
```

and It also doesn't work.

What can be the problem.

Comment: It looks like you miss the share name in your examples: net use t: \\yourpc\sharename yourpassword /user:yourusername   In what cases does it fail? any errors?

Comment: @rene: I added the share name, It doesn't work. There is no error (the .bat file works well locally).

Answer (score 0):

Try mapping the share, then change to that drive before using `xcopy`

```
net use M: \\the-ip-of-the-remote-computer mypassword /myuser
pushd M:\
xcopy folder\filetocopy C:\yourcdrivefolder
```