# How to move a ClearCase vob when UNC style sharing is not allowed?

Tags: windows, clearcase, windows-server-2008-r2

I am going to move a ClearCase vob from Windows 2000 to Windows 2008 server within same domain. But, I cannot access vob storage directory from windows 2008 server using `\\hostname`.

But I cannot use `\\` here as it doesn't work. It allows file transfer only over RDP. Please advise how I can move the move in this case.

So, I have two questions :

1) [Document says](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_8.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_admin.doc/topics/t_mvvob_win_indomain.htm):

> You must run ccopy on the host to which the VOB is being moved.

```
C:\ClearCaseStorage\VOBs> net use E: \\vobsvr01\vobstg
C:\ClearCaseStorage\VOBs> ccopy libpub.vbs E:\libpub.vbs
```

Is this correct because if I go to destination I will not have the `.vbs` file, then how `ccopy` can be used on the destination as advised above?

2) I cannot use UNC style sharing (`\\`) I can only use file transfer over rdp.

Please clarify on how I can move the vob in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As illustrated in IBM technote "[ccopy fails copying a VOB between Windows clients](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21178374)", you can use shared drive to copy the vob between Windows server.

For that, you can use the [shared drive utility on W2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/272519)

You can also check if using [`net use \\ip.of.remote.computer` works too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13876630/6309).

Comment: thanks. I am still a bit confused with the ibm support doc. does it mean copy vob storage using normal copy paste to the destination and then run ccopy on the destination?

Comment: @user2636464 the doc lists commands (ccopy, register, mktag) to be done from the source vob server only.

Comment: But moving vobs section says "You must run ccopy on the host to which the VOB is being moved. " which mean ccopy to be run from the target server?

Comment: @user2636464 indeed: target server, which means you must have a share path pointing to the source server.